# How can I pass module parameters for bonding driver when compiled into kernel 2.4?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, bonding

I have an old 2.4 kernel based linux device using NIC Bonding. Instead of having the NIC Bonding module build as a module and `modprobe`'ed into the system, its compiled directly into the kernel. I'd like to modify the module parameters to add `mode=1 miimon=100` in order to get it to not use round-robbin packet sending, but all of the examples I'm finding seem to assume the module is not compiled into the kernel, or just don't seem to work for me.

So far I've tried modifying my `/etc/modules.conf` file to try adding

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bond0 mode=1 miimon=100
options bonding mode=1 miimon=100
```

Based on something else I found on line I've tried adding bond0.mode=1 and bonding.mode=1 to my kernel commandline in grub, but regardless, when I boot up and check 'cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0' I always see staring back at me this line:

```
Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
```

I've tried looking for a setting to change in `sysctl` or `/proc` but am coming up empty.

Comment: The `module.parameter=value` syntax is documented in `kernel-parameters.txt` for recent kernel versions, but not in 2.4, so this is presumably a recent(-ish) feature. I had a quick look at the source (`include/module.h`) and there doesn't seem to be an equivalent feature in 2.4, nor (in `drivers/net/bonding/bond_main.c`) do I see another way to set these parameters.

Comment: How old is old?  It looks like this was in 2.4.22: http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/drivers/net/bonding/bond_main.c?v=linux-2.4.22

Comment: My particular kernel is 2.4.37

Comment: How did you (so far) try searching in `/sys` and `/proc`? Please describe a bit, maybe some new ideas will come up.

Comment: Could you paste the output of `ls -l /proc/net/bonding/`?

Comment: Why are your stuck with that old kernel and why can`t you recompile it? I understand you propably have a "black box" that has this kernel. Often there are ways to boot a different kernel (by booting from USB instead from ROM).

Comment: @Nils- Yes its an "appliance" installed in a rack several thousand miles away from my desk . I can indeed recompile and ship out a new kernel and find someone onsite to talk through the upgrade, I've been working on that currently in fact , but its a long and painful process and was hoping there was an easier way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it - but it's bad news, unfortunately. Here's what `Documentation/networking/bonding.txt` file for 2.4.37.11 says:

`It is recommended
to configure the driver as module since`**`it is currently the only way to
pass parameters to the driver`**`and configure more than one bonding device.`

So *no module = no changing of parameters* in this case. Sorry.